# QSL cards from shortwave listeners

Tags: qsl-card

I received a few eQSL's from shortwave listeners.

Should I send an eQSL back or just archive these QSLs? Also, is it possible to receive a paper QSL card from a SWL?

UPD: The reason why I asked this question is that eQSL.cc has certain rules regarding sending QSLs for QSOs that didn't happen. I'm not sure whether it will count as if I had a QSO with an SWL (which naturally couldn't happen) if I respond.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I think I found an answer to my own question after Mike helped to word the right question :) The [eQSL.cc FAQ](http://www.eqsl.cc/qslcard/FAQ-Old.cfm) says:

> **How do I handle SWL cards?** When a user sets the SWL/HAM checkbox in
>   his Profile to SWL, it automatically forces all incoming and outgoing
>   cards to say 'Confirming SWL Reception' instead of the usual 'This
>   Confirms Our 2-Way QSO'. If you are an SWL, just make sure to go to My
>   Profile and set yourself up as an SWL. If you are a ham, when you send
>   an eQSL to an SWL, it will automatically put the correct wording into
>   the card.

Also according to [this discussion](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/5104/minimal-info-on-a-swl-qsl) SWLs do send paper QSL cards.

Answer (score 1):

I receive SWL QSL cards every few years. And I usually respond, especially if they include an SASE.

But why not also respond to eQSLs? In either case, you might make someone's day. :-)

Comment: I am waaay overdue to check my eQSL account (I forgot that I had one until now).

Comment: I would be only happy to respond. The reason why I asked this question is that eQSL.cc has certain rules regarding sending QSLs for QSOs that didn't happen. I'm not sure whether it will count as if I had a QSO with an SWL if I respond.